# Download cipher-suite pack in Windows

Tags: windows, protocol, internet-security, tls

Is it possible to download and install a cipher-suite pack in Windows, in the same manner as I would for a font suite?  Or am I asking too much?

Gordon.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to download and install a cipher-suite pack in Windows

No. The cipher suites are compiled into a library and available through [SChannel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380123%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You can tune some behavior, but its usually limited to disabling algorithms and cipher suites that exist. See, for example, [How to restrict the use of certain cryptographic algorithms and protocols in Schannel.dll](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245030).